# Extension groups in quotient categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, cohomology, derived-categories, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a [Serre subcategory](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02MN) of $\mathcal{A}$. We can form the [quotient category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_an_abelian_category) $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$, and the canonical functor $Q:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$ is exact. As such, given $X$ and $Y$ two objects in $\mathcal{A}$, there is a group morphism
$$
q:\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{A}}(X,Y)\to \operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}}(Q(X),Q(Y))
$$
induced by $Q$ on the extension groups. Do we know something on the image or the kernel of $q$?